# Fastest/most efficient way to check log timestamp sequence

Tags: bash

I noticed recently while checking a routers log that there were log entries out of sequence. The entries are appended sequencially so it means that the router was changing it's date and time during operation, not something that should happen. Obviously this is something I need to check for in future but this is a large router and can produce a LOT of log entries. These rotate and are compressed at the 1Mb mark, and are rotated overall at 11 files. (filename.0.gz to filename.9.gz and the current, uncompressed file filename).

I therefor need to check all 11 files for entries that are timestamped out of sequence, a LOT of logs to check. With this amount of logging to check through, obviously the smallest amount of time saved with the overall operation, and the actual script used, could make a huge difference in the running time, and CPU load.

I've got a few dozen routers to check. I was going to pull all the log files back to my Linux server, uncompress them and make them into a single file, and then write a script to check the sequence.

What's the most efficient way to do this please?

Comment: 11 Mb doesn't sound that much. Just try a clean, naive solution and see how slow that goes first. Then ask a specific optimization question with code example.

Comment: 11Mb not too much? Oh, OK, thanks.

Comment: My Log timestamp is in the format: Sep 17 11:28:24 2014 Is there some clever date conversion command or do I slice the line into individual variables, convert the Month to a number, and then have a tedious nested comparison: Is the year -ge Is the Month -ge Is the Day -ge etc etc?

Comment: With GNU date at least `date -d 'Sep 17 11:28:24 2014' +%s` will get you that time in seconds since the epoch.

Comment: Thanks!!    todate=$(date -d 'Sep 17 11:28:24 2014' +%s) works very nicely :-)

Comment: Sounds like a job for Hadoop to me ;)

Comment: Hadoop? I've not heard of him/it/them before.

Comment: Ah no Hadoop is not MY answer.